# Detecting iBeacons with different UUIDs

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I'm trying to use UUIDs as identifiers for specific beacons (using phones in this case). I understand that major and minor are used to do this, but I'd rather use the UUID, or the identifier string.

With that being said, is there anyway to scan for beacons regardless of UUIDs with the CLBeacon API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Android you can scan for all UUIDs.  On iOS you cannot.  See:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

On iOS, CoreLocation limits you to monitoring for at most 20 different UUIDs.  Ranging does not have a limit of 20, but you still must know the UUIDs ahead of time.

Comment: Are you sure, can we monitor different beacons with different UUIDs from the same App in iOS. (20 different UUIDs)

Comment: Yes, this is true and mentioned in my answer.  But the question was about detecting iBeacons *regardless* of UUID, which is not possible.  To be clear, the 20 region limit on iOS only applies to monitoring.  You can range many more regions, but still must set up the UUIDs ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no restriction in monitoring iBeacon regions with different UUID. You can do something like:

```
NSArray *uuids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"####-####-###1", @"####-####-###2", nil];
for (NSString *uuidString in uuids) {
    CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString] identifier:identifier];
    region.notifyOnEntry = entry;
    region.notifyOnExit = exit;
    region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

You just need to make sure you check for the UUID in you locationManager's delegate methods. You can use something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        NSLog(@"ProximityUUID:%@", beaconRegion.proximityUUID);
        NSLog(@"ProximityMajor:%@", beaconRegion.major);
        NSLog(@"ProximityMinorD:%@", beaconRegion.minor);
    }
}
```

You should see that the delegate method is called with different UUIDs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the comment mamnun. However, what if I have hundreds/thousands of different UUIDs that I wish to monitor, some of which might not be in the vicinity of the scanner. Of course I wouldn't be able to scan for all of them - so I guess there isn't a method to just sniff for all available UUIDs in the air?

Comment: If you have "hundreds/thousands" of different UUIDs that you want, then either a) you've designed your system quite poorly and failed to make use of the 4+ billion unique major/minor codes available within each UUID, or b) you intended to detect beacons belonging to other people who aren't willing to cooperate with you by putting their beacons in a handful of common UUID's.  In the first case, it's your mistake, in the second, Apple probably doesn't intend for you to do that, regardless of the fact that it is possible with other BLE implementations.

Comment: I wish Chris Stratton's comment could be the official answer here. Very well said.