# How do I use CoreLocation to get multiple iBeacons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, ibeacon

I'm trying to use CoreLocation to get multiple iBeacons as specified by my iOS app- the idea is that if they're in range, it'll notify me for each one as it finds them.

The problem is that in the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods, I have to provide a CLBeaconRegion object. There's one of these for every iBeacon, and if I was just using one iBeacon, I could just use that one, but since there are several, I need to know how to find each CLBeaconRegion from those methods.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this works; if so, please let me know.

```
- (void)getForUUUIDs:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
        //Get an array of UUID's to filter by
        self->locationUUIDs = [self getArgsObject:command.arguments];

        self->locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self->locationManager.delegate = self;
        scanCallback = command.callbackId;

        for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [locationUUIDs count]; i++) {
            NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLERegion %d",i];
            CLBeaconRegion *thisRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[locationUUIDs  allKeys] objectAtIndex:i] identifier:identifier];
            [self->locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:thisRegion];
        }
}

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    [self->locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:????];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    [self->locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:????];
}
```

Comment: Do you really neew more than one UUID? It would be _a lot_ easier playing with _Major/Minor_.

Comment: You misunderstand. Our customers will input the UUID's they use to our system, and the app will report on which of these the device can detect. I'm not interested in location at the moment, I just collect the information and send it back. I don't even know what iBeacons they'll be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ranging on the same region that fired the monitor entry/exit event is extremely simple:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    [self->locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}
```

This will start ranging on the exact same region you used to start monitoring.  Note that there is a region parameter passed to the callback.  That Region parameter will include the same UUID that you set up before.

One other point:  while there is nothing wrong with starting ranging when you enter a region and stopping ranging when you exit a region, there is really no need to do this.  Just start ranging the same time you start monitoring.  Because ranging won't do anything when the iBeacon isn't visible, the end result will be almost identical.  The only difference is you will probably get your first ranging callback one second sooner if you set it up ahead of time.  There is no extra drain on battery or system resources.

The added benefit of setting it up ahead of time is that you don't have to do the casting of the CLRegion object -- you have the original object to begin with.  And you don't have to implement the monitoring callback methods, so your code is simpler.  Like this:

```
- (void)getForUUUIDs:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    //Get an array of UUID's to filter by
    self->locationUUIDs = [self getArgsObject:command.arguments];

    self->locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self->locationManager.delegate = self;
    scanCallback = command.callbackId;

    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [locationUUIDs count]; i++) {
        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLERegion %d",i];
        CLBeaconRegion *thisRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[locationUUIDs  allKeys] objectAtIndex:i] identifier:identifier];
        [self->locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:thisRegion];
        [self->locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:thisRegion];
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but what I get back is of type CLRegion, not CLBeaconRegion, and the methods require a CLBeaconRegion.

Comment: Oh, right.  Simple fix: just cast it. I have edited my answer to show this.

Comment: You are like the god of iBeacons. Thanks a lot, clearly my rudimentary understanding of Objective-C was letting me down (or a lack of imagination, perhaps).

Comment: @davidgyoung I read some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834211/detecting-ibeacons-with-different-uuids that maximum 20 Regions can monitor by an App at a time, so in above case if the  `locationUUIDs` exceeds the app works fine?

Comment: Unlike monitoring which has a 20 region limit, you can range as many beacon regions as you like -- there is no limit.  That said, the *first* code block above work if you run out of monitoring regions because you'll never get an entry callback for the regions in excess of 20.   The second code block above will work to start ranging even for more than 20 regions.

Answer (score 0):

your region is specified by a uuid

```
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                       identifier:identifier];
```

All your beacons must share that uuid. So when you range your beacons, you can get them in that method (CLLocationManagerDelegate).

```
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {
        NSLog(@"Major : %@", beacon.major);
        NSLog(@"Minor : %@", beacon.minor);
    }
}
```

The attributes major and minor are here to differentiate your beacons.

Comment: But I have multiple UUID's that I'm using. So I'm iterating around them and specifying the region. But due to the asynchronicity of it I don't know which CLRegion (when it comes back with a region) accords to each CLBeaconRegion (which I start it with).

Comment: I wrote an short explanation in the answer above.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I won't know which element of the array to get, because I won't know which region it's entering/exiting. Asynchronicity at it's finest, I suppose.